# Issue with imported order

Tags: magento2, product, php, orders, magento2.2

I import all my orders from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2, the orders are in the store but when I press on View button, I have the following error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/magento/vendor/magento/module-weee/Helper/Data.php on line 533

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/magento/vendor/magento/module-weee/Helper/Data.php on line 533
#0 /home/magento/vendor/magento/module-weee/Helper/Data.php(533): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/magento/...', 533, Array)
#1 /home/magento/vendor/magento/module-weee/Block/Item/Price/Renderer.php(448): Magento\Weee\Helper\Data->getBaseRowWeeeTaxInclTax(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item\Interceptor))
#2 /home/magento/vendor/magento/module-weee/Block/Adminhtml/Items/Price/Renderer.php(185): Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer->getBaseTotalAmount(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item\Interceptor))
#3 /home/magento/vendor/magento/module-weee/view/adminhtml/templates/items/price/total.phtml(16): Magento\Weee\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Price\Renderer->getBaseTotalAmount(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item\Interceptor))
```

What does this mean? Is there any way to fix this?

I add here the entire error:

https://paste.ofcode.org/ZU3EJ5GrGkfQ28L4z3fkKT

**EDIT:**

At line 533 in the file vendor/magento/module-weee/Helper/Data.php on line 533, I have the following code, I try to add a var_dump but is not work.

```
foreach ($weeeTaxAppliedAmounts as $weeeTaxAppliedAmount => $test) {
    var_dump($test);
    $totalWeeeTaxIncTaxApplied += max($weeeTaxAppliedAmount['base_row_amount_incl_tax'], 0);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be some custom fields coming over from Magento 1 but doesn't have a default value when you create the columns in Magento 2.2

However the best way to tackle your problem would be to use xdebug and put a breakpoint in `/module-weee/Helper/Data.php`

If not possbile you can just add var_dump before the error line and check what's the value passing in the foreach loop.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I can't add xdebug there and I try to add a var_dump there but is not work. I edit my answer and I add what code is there and how I add var_dump, can you take a look please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Not sure why it appears, but if you add some conditions in getRowWeeeTaxInclTax() and getRowWeeeTaxInclTax() in /vendor/magento/module-weee/Helper/Data.php

Is it a bug or somthing we have to check in database?

```
public function getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($item)
{
    $weeeTaxAppliedAmounts = $this->getApplied($item);
    $totalWeeeTaxIncTaxApplied = 0;
    /* just added */
    if(is_array($weeeTaxAppliedAmounts)){
    foreach ($weeeTaxAppliedAmounts as $weeeTaxAppliedAmount) {
        $totalWeeeTaxIncTaxApplied += max($weeeTaxAppliedAmount['row_amount_incl_tax'], 0);
    }
    }
    return $totalWeeeTaxIncTaxApplied;
}

/**
 * Get the total base weee including tax by row
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
 * @return float
 */
public function getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($item)
{
    $weeeTaxAppliedAmounts = $this->getApplied($item);
    $totalWeeeTaxIncTaxApplied = 0;
    /* just added */ 
    if(is_array($weeeTaxAppliedAmounts)){
      foreach ($weeeTaxAppliedAmounts as $weeeTaxAppliedAmount) {
          $totalWeeeTaxIncTaxApplied += max($weeeTaxAppliedAmount['base_row_amount_incl_tax'], 0);
      }
    }
    return $totalWeeeTaxIncTaxApplied;
}
```

Comment: It may be related to https://gielberkers.com/properly-calculate-fptweee-configurable-products-magento-2/

Comment: this was related to migrated data

Comment: where is the first getBaseRowWeeeTaxInclTax()?